# Pattern for Queue Action Processing

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, asp.net-mvc, design-patterns

I have a table containing Queued elements for synchronization issues with another system

```
TableName | PrimaryKey | Action    
--------------------------------
Products       15         Delete
Products       21         Create  
Categories      9         Update
```

**TableName** : The name of the targeted SQL table

**PrimaryKey** : The PK value of the targeted element within the corresponding table

**Action** : Action to do *(Example : If create -> Push the creation of the element with ID number 21 of the local table Products in the remote system)*

What I need is a way to handle this properly in C#. I am thinking in using the Command Pattern. (ASP.Net MVC4/C#)

Do you have any guidance about this type of issues ?

Comment: +1 for nice question! But I think you need to create a logic(`Loop`) to do this in C#

Comment: Thank you. I am still looking for a solution, and I do not really find a celean way to implement this

Answer (score 1):

You can use advice from [that article](http://rusanu.com/2010/03/26/using-tables-as-queues/) and process queue on server side. Then your code could look like

```
create table TQueue (TableName nvarchar(128), PrimaryKey int, Action nvarchar(128))

create procedure sp_TQueue_Pop
as
begin
    declare @TableName nvarchar(128), @PrimaryKey int, @Action nvarchar(128)
    declare @temp_pop table (TableName nvarchar(128), PrimaryKey int, Action nvarchar(128))

    begin transaction

    select @TableName = null, @PrimaryKey = null, @Action = null

    delete top (1)
    from TQueue with (rowlock, readpast)
    output deleted.* into @temp_pop

    select @TableName = TableName, @PrimaryKey = PrimaryKey, @Action = Action
    from @temp_pop

    --================================================
    --  do your processing here
    --================================================

    select @TableName, @PrimaryKey, @Action
end
```

to dequeue you have just execute procedure.

Hope that helps.